How to overlay text on the navigation bar in SwiftUI without expanding the toolbar height?
I’m working on a SwiftUI project where I want to display a username and status text (like “Last seen recently”) at the center of the navigation bar.
My goal is to overlay the text in the navigation bar, keeping the height unchanged, and ensuring the text is centered. I would also like to have a trailing user avatar aligned to the right.
[]
[]
I initially used the .toolbar modifier with the .principal placement to center a VStack containing the username and status text. However, this caused the toolbar to expand vertically, which I didn’t expect. I also experimented with GeometryReader to control alignment, but that didn’t produce the desired result either.

If you don't want the height to change, try specifying the navigation title display mode: .toolbarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)

Yes, it really helped. Thanks for sharing your knowledge

You should post your updated code as an answer here below and then mark it as a solution so it can helpful to others as well. Include a screenshot of the final result too if possible.

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(0..<15) { _ in
                /*
                 Временная заглушка
                 Placeholder content
                 */
                Text("PLACEHOLDER")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 200)
                    .background(Color.appAccentColor)
            }
        }
    }
    .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
    .toolbar {
        trailingUserAvatar()
        toolbarUserInfo()
    }
    .toolbarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) // <--
    .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
        TextInputArea()
            .background(Color(.systemBackground))
    }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community? Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code
